# Lotus Notes Copy As Table throws error "Your table exceeds the maximum allowed table width"

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a user that is selecting all documents from a view (about 1000 documents) with 20 columns.

The user continually receives this message:
[image]

The user cannot select either of those choices -- the dialog is "frozen".

I have never seen this message and I cannot find a solution to this.

I have tried to reproduce on Mac OS running both 8.5.x and 9.0 as well as Windows running both 8.5.x and 9.0.  I cannot reproduce this -- it seems that one user is having this issue.

Any help would be great on this.

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to copy it to. You can export selected documents as "tabular text". You can then import it into Excel, and format it, or whatever you want.

1. Select all documents (CTRL-A)
2. Select File-> Export
3. Select the file and set the "save as type" as "Tabular Text". (File name can be anything eg. export.txt.

File is exported as "fixed width" not CSV.